# Laravel Homestead - ‘no input file specified’

Tags: laravel, homestead

I've set up the project many times, but this time, when I use vagrant up and try to go into the website, it says "no input file specified".

- I have set up the hosts file
- **I have logged to the vagrant ssh to ensure the files/folders are linking and they are**
- I have tried destroying the virtual machine, building it again, --provision etc..

This is the code for the project from the Homestead file

```
folders:
    -
    map: ~/portfolio
    to: /home/vagrant/code  
sites:
    -
    map: portfolio.test
    to: /home/vagrant/code/public
    php: "7.2"
```

No matter what I do, I just go between the errors "No input file specified" and "403 Forbidden
nginx/1.15.6"

Answer (score 0):

Check if your path are correct and the folders exist. 
Open your command line and move to the location and run following command

`pwd`

That is going to return the path.

You are also not pointing in to your actual project, shouldn't this:

```
folders:
    -
    map: ~/portfolio
    to: /home/vagrant/code  
sites:
    -
    map: portfolio.test
    to: /home/vagrant/code/public
    php: "7.2"
```

be something like this:

```
folders:
    -
    map: ~/portfolio
    to: /home/vagrant/code
sites:
    -
    map: portfolio.test
    to: /home/vagrant/code/myapp/public
    php: "7.2"
```

Further you should try following:

`homestead up --provision`

or

`vagrant up --provision`

Comment: Yes, I have tried and the paths are correct, I also ran the command with provision. Same error. As for the folder on the virtual machine, it's right in the code folder, there is no subfolder with a project name, as I work only on one project. It was like that before, and it worked, it does not make a difference.

Comment: @CritingZ could you try to create a project (subfolder) inside code?